# use file name for multiple routers in Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I want use filename in multiple rotuers

```
 @Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("file:C:/inputFolder").setHeader("CamelFileName").recipientList(header("CamelFileName"),"direct:route1,direct:route1")
```

I'm created header parameter as CamelFileName and passing that to recipientList.

Answer (score 0):

Moreover, after recipient list header values will be gone. You better set the filename to property and then it can be used in 'n' of routes.